# Minefield - A Cross Platform Minesweeper clone

Tags: c++, game, c++17, qt

[image]

[image]

I just finished a full minesweeper clone which is based on [Minesweeper for Windows 95](http://www.minesweeper.info/downloads/Winmine95.html).

I used C++ and Qt to realize it. The full source code can be find in [my git hub](https://github.com/sandro4912/Minefield).

Since this is too much code too review, I want to focus on the logic of the cells. For that I created the following classes:

- `Cell`: Represents a single cell in the `Minefield`
- `CellInputHandler`: This `QEventfilter` gets installed on each `Cell` to manage movements and right and left clicks with the cells.
- `Minefield`: Manages all the cells' events and tells the game when important events happen (bomb hit, uncovered all safe cells, uncovered first cell).

You wonder why `CellInputHandler` handles the events and not each individual `Cell` directly. Minesweeper supports the following movement which could not be directly implemented in a single cell:

- press left mouse button on `Cell` A and hold it.
- Move out of `Cell` A  ⟶ `Cell` A gets "unpressed" on move out
- Move into `Cell` B ⟶ `Cell` B gets "pressed"

In the Cells directly implemented, I could not detect moving into the Cell with a pressed Mouse Button. So an event filter was the solution. Still, I feel this is a strange solution because I have to make it a friend of `Cell` and friends are often a bad design choice.

So please let me know what you think about the code. Also tell me any other bad practices or improvements I could have made.

Feel free to also check the other classes in the repo. If there's anything strange, let me know.

#### cell.h

```
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H

#include <QWidget>

#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QTimer>

class CellInputHandler;

class Cell : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum class State{
        empty,
        mine
    };

    Cell(State state, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void setCountOfNeighbourMines(int count);
    [[nodiscard]] int countOfNeighbourMines() const;

    [[nodiscard]] bool hasMine() const;
    [[nodiscard]] bool hasQuestionmark() const;
    [[nodiscard]] bool isCovered() const;
    [[nodiscard]] bool isFLagged() const;
    [[nodiscard]] bool isPressed() const;
    [[nodiscard]] bool neighbourHasMine() const;
    [[nodiscard]] bool neighbourIsFlagged() const;

public slots:
    void toggleColor(bool value);
    void toggleNewQuestionMarks(bool value);

    void increaseCountOfFlaggedNeighbours();
    void decreaseCountOfFlaggedNeighbours();
    void uncoverIfCoveredAndNoMine();
    void uncoverIfNotFlagged();

    void pressIfCoveredOrQuestionmark();
    void releaseIfCoveredOrQuestionmarkPressed();

    void showMine();
    void setToFlaggedWrong();

signals:
    void hitMine();
    void flagged();
    void unflagged();
    void uncovered();
    void uncoveredEmptyCell();
    void uncoverAreaWithNoMines();
    void uncoverNotFlaggedNeighbours();
    void pressed();
    void released();
    void pressNeighbours();
    void releaseNeighbours();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private slots:
    void mark();

private:
    enum class DisplayType{
        covered,
        coveredPressed,
        neigboursHave0Mines,
        neigboursHave1Mine,
        neigboursHave2Mines,
        neigboursHave3Mines,
        neigboursHave4Mines,
        neigboursHave5Mines,
        neigboursHave6Mines,
        neigboursHave7Mines,
        neigboursHave8Mines,
        questionmark,
        questionmarkPressed,
        flagged,
        mine,
        mineExploded,
        flaggedWrong,
    };

    QImage displayImage(DisplayType type);

    void uncover();
    void uncoverMine();
    void setToUncoveredDisplayType();

    friend class CellInputHandler;

    void handleMousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void handleMouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

    void handleMouseMoveEventInsideLeftButton(QMouseEvent *event);
    void handleMouseMoveEventOutsideLeftButton(QMouseEvent *event);

    void handleMouseMoveEventInsideBothButtons(QMouseEvent *event);
    void handleMouseMoveEventOutsideBothButtons(QMouseEvent *event);

    const bool mHasMine;
    bool mNeighboursPressed;
    bool mQuestionMarksOn;
    bool mColorOn;
    int mCountOfNeighbourMines;
    int mCountOfNeigboursFlagged;
    QElapsedTimer mElapsedTimer;
    QTimer mSingleMouseTimerLeft;
    QTimer mSingleMouseTimerRight;
    DisplayType mDisplayType;
};

#endif // CELL_H
```

#### cell.cpp

```
#include "cell.h"

#include "converttograyscale.h"
#include "cellinputhandler.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStylePainter>
#include <QStyleOptionButton>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QImage>

#include <QDebug>

Cell::Cell(Cell::State state, QWidget *parent)
    :QWidget{ parent },
      mHasMine{ static_cast<bool>(state) },
      mNeighboursPressed{ false },
      mQuestionMarksOn{ true },
      mColorOn{ true },
      mCountOfNeighbourMines{ 0 },
      mCountOfNeigboursFlagged{ 0 },
      mDisplayType{ DisplayType::covered }
{
    setFixedSize(displayImage(mDisplayType).size());

    mElapsedTimer.start();

    constexpr auto intervall = 50;
    for(QTimer* timer : {&mSingleMouseTimerRight, &mSingleMouseTimerLeft}){
        timer->setInterval(intervall);
        timer->setSingleShot(true);
    }

    connect(&mSingleMouseTimerLeft, &QTimer::timeout,
            this, &Cell::pressIfCoveredOrQuestionmark);
    connect(&mSingleMouseTimerRight, &QTimer::timeout,
            this, &Cell::mark);

    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void Cell::setCountOfNeighbourMines(int count)
{
    constexpr auto minNeighbourMines = 0;
    constexpr auto maxNeighbourMines = 8;

    Q_ASSERT(count >= minNeighbourMines && count <= maxNeighbourMines);

    mCountOfNeighbourMines = count;
}

int Cell::countOfNeighbourMines() const
{
    return mCountOfNeighbourMines;
}

bool Cell::hasMine() const
{
    return mHasMine;
}

bool Cell::hasQuestionmark() const
{
    return mDisplayType == DisplayType::questionmark;
}

bool Cell::isCovered() const
{
    return mDisplayType == DisplayType::covered;
}

bool Cell::isFLagged() const
{
    return mDisplayType == DisplayType::flagged;
}

bool Cell::isPressed() const
{
    return mDisplayType == DisplayType::coveredPressed ||
            mDisplayType == DisplayType::questionmarkPressed;
}

bool Cell::neighbourHasMine() const
{
    return mCountOfNeighbourMines != 0;
}

bool Cell::neighbourIsFlagged() const
{
    return mCountOfNeigboursFlagged != 0;
}

void Cell::toggleColor(bool value)
{
    mColorOn = value;
    update();
}

void Cell::toggleNewQuestionMarks(bool value)
{
    mQuestionMarksOn = value;
}

void Cell::increaseCountOfFlaggedNeighbours()
{
    ++mCountOfNeigboursFlagged;
    Q_ASSERT(mCountOfNeigboursFlagged <= 8);
}

void Cell::decreaseCountOfFlaggedNeighbours()
{
    --mCountOfNeigboursFlagged;
    Q_ASSERT(mCountOfNeigboursFlagged >= 0);
}

void Cell::uncoverIfCoveredAndNoMine()
{
    if (hasMine() || !isCovered()) {
        return;
    }

    setToUncoveredDisplayType();
    update();

    if(!neighbourHasMine()) {
        emit uncoverAreaWithNoMines();
    }
}

void Cell::uncoverIfNotFlagged()
{
    if (isFLagged() || mDisplayType == DisplayType::flaggedWrong) {
        return;
    }

    uncover();
    update();

    if(!neighbourHasMine()) {
        emit uncoverAreaWithNoMines();
    }
}

void Cell::pressIfCoveredOrQuestionmark()
{ 
    if(mSingleMouseTimerLeft.isActive()) {
        mSingleMouseTimerLeft.stop();
    }

    if(mDisplayType == DisplayType::covered) {
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::coveredPressed;
        emit pressed();
        update();
    }
    else if(mDisplayType == DisplayType::questionmark) {
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::questionmarkPressed;
        emit pressed();
        update();
    }
}

void Cell::releaseIfCoveredOrQuestionmarkPressed()
{
    if(mSingleMouseTimerLeft.isActive()) {
        mSingleMouseTimerLeft.stop();
    }

    if(mDisplayType == DisplayType::coveredPressed) {
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::covered;
        emit released();
        update();
    }
    else if(mDisplayType == DisplayType::questionmarkPressed) {
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::questionmark;
        emit released();
        update();
    }
}

void Cell::showMine()
{
    if(hasMine()) {
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::mine;
        update();
    }
}

void Cell::setToFlaggedWrong()
{
    mDisplayType = DisplayType::flaggedWrong;
    update();
}

void Cell::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)
    QPainter painter{ this };

    auto image = displayImage(mDisplayType);

    if(!mColorOn) {
        image = convertToGrayscale(image);
    }

    painter.drawImage(rect(), image);
}

void Cell::mark()
{
    switch (mDisplayType) {
    case DisplayType::covered:
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::flagged;
        emit flagged();
        update();
        break;
    case DisplayType::flagged:
        if(mQuestionMarksOn) {
            mDisplayType = DisplayType::questionmark;
        }
        else {
            mDisplayType = DisplayType::covered;
        }
        emit unflagged();
        update();
        break;
    case DisplayType::questionmark:
        mDisplayType = DisplayType::covered;
        update();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

QImage Cell::displayImage(Cell::DisplayType type)
{
    switch(type){
        case DisplayType::covered:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_covered.png"};
        case DisplayType::coveredPressed:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_covered_pressed.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave0Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_0.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave1Mine:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_1.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave2Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_2.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave3Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_3.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave4Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_4.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave5Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_5.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave6Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_6.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave7Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_7.png"};
        case DisplayType::neigboursHave8Mines:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_8.png"};
        case DisplayType::questionmark:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_questionmark.png"};
        case DisplayType::questionmarkPressed:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_questionmark_pressed.png"};
        case DisplayType::flagged:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_flagged.png"};
        case DisplayType::mine:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_mine.png"};
        case DisplayType::mineExploded:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_mine_explode.png"};
        case DisplayType::flaggedWrong:
            return QImage{":/ressources/cell_nomine.png"};
    }
    return QImage{};
}

void Cell::uncover()
{
    if(hasMine()) {
        uncoverMine();
    }
    else {
        setToUncoveredDisplayType();
    }
    emit uncovered();
    update();
}

void Cell::uncoverMine()
{
    mDisplayType = DisplayType::mineExploded;
    emit hitMine();
}

void Cell::setToUncoveredDisplayType()
{
    mDisplayType = static_cast<DisplayType>(
    static_cast<int>(
        DisplayType::neigboursHave0Mines) + mCountOfNeighbourMines);
    emit uncoveredEmptyCell();
}


void Cell::handleMousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(!(event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) ||
         event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton))) {
        return;
    }

    if(event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton)) {
        mSingleMouseTimerLeft.start();
    }
    else if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton)){
        mSingleMouseTimerRight.start();
    }

    const auto elapsedTime = mElapsedTimer.restart();

    if(elapsedTime >= QApplication::doubleClickInterval()) {
        return;
    }

    if((mSingleMouseTimerLeft.isActive() &&
        event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton)) ||
        (mSingleMouseTimerRight.isActive() &&
         event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton))){

        if(!isPressed()) {
            pressIfCoveredOrQuestionmark();
            mNeighboursPressed = true;
            emit pressNeighbours();
        }
        for(QTimer* timer : { &mSingleMouseTimerRight,
            &mSingleMouseTimerLeft }) {
            timer->stop();
        }
    }
}

void Cell::handleMouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(mNeighboursPressed) {
        if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton ||
                event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            mNeighboursPressed = false;

            if(mCountOfNeigboursFlagged == mCountOfNeighbourMines) {
                if(isPressed()) {
                    uncover();
                }
                emit uncoverNotFlaggedNeighbours();
                emit uncoverAreaWithNoMines();
            }
            else {
                if(isPressed()) {
                    releaseIfCoveredOrQuestionmarkPressed();
                }
                emit releaseNeighbours();
            }
        }
    }
    else if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        uncover();

        if(mDisplayType == DisplayType::neigboursHave0Mines) {
            emit uncoverAreaWithNoMines();
        }
    }
}

void Cell::handleMouseMoveEventInsideLeftButton(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)

    if(!isPressed()) {
        pressIfCoveredOrQuestionmark();
    }
}

void Cell::handleMouseMoveEventOutsideLeftButton(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)

    if(mSingleMouseTimerLeft.isActive()) {
        mSingleMouseTimerLeft.stop();
    }

    if(isPressed()) {
        releaseIfCoveredOrQuestionmarkPressed();
    }
}

void Cell::handleMouseMoveEventInsideBothButtons(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    handleMouseMoveEventInsideLeftButton(event);

    mNeighboursPressed = true;
    emit pressNeighbours();

}

void Cell::handleMouseMoveEventOutsideBothButtons(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    handleMouseMoveEventOutsideLeftButton(event);

    if(mNeighboursPressed) {
        mNeighboursPressed = false;
        emit releaseNeighbours();
    }
}
```

#### cellinputhandler.h

```
#ifndef CELLINPUTHANDLER_H
#define CELLINPUTHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QTimer>

class Cell;
class QMouseEvent;

class CellInputHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CellInputHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;

private:
    void handleMouseButtonPressEvents(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
    void handleMouseButtonReleaseEvents(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
    void handleMouseMoveEvents(QEvent *event);

    void cellMoveInsideHandle(Cell *cell, QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
    void cellMoveOutsideHandle(Cell *cell, QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);

    Cell *mLastCell;
};

#endif // CELLINPUTHANDLER_H
```

#### cellinputhandler.cpp

```
#include "cellinputhandler.h"

#include "cell.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

#include <QDebug>

CellInputHandler::CellInputHandler(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{ parent },
      mLastCell{ nullptr }
{
}

bool CellInputHandler::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
        handleMouseButtonPressEvents(watched, event);
        return true;
    }
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
        handleMouseButtonReleaseEvents(watched, event);
        return true;
    }
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
        handleMouseMoveEvents(event);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void CellInputHandler::handleMouseButtonPressEvents(
        QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    auto cell = qobject_cast<Cell *>(watched);

    cell->handleMousePressEvent(mouseEvent);

    mLastCell = cell;
}

void CellInputHandler::handleMouseButtonReleaseEvents(
        QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(watched)

    auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    auto widget = QApplication::widgetAt(QCursor::pos());
    auto cell = qobject_cast<Cell *>(widget);

    if(cell) {
        cell->handleMouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
        mLastCell = cell;
    }
    else if(mLastCell) {
        mLastCell->handleMouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
    }
}

void CellInputHandler::handleMouseMoveEvents(QEvent *event)
{
    auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);

    if(mouseEvent->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton)) {
        auto widget = QApplication::widgetAt(mouseEvent->globalPos());

        if(widget) {
            auto cell = qobject_cast<Cell *>(widget);

            if(mLastCell && (!cell || cell != mLastCell)) {
                cellMoveOutsideHandle(mLastCell, mouseEvent);
            }
            if(!cell) {
                mLastCell = nullptr;
            }
            else if(cell != mLastCell) {
                cellMoveInsideHandle(cell, mouseEvent);
                mLastCell = cell;
            }
        }
    }
}

void CellInputHandler::cellMoveInsideHandle(
        Cell *cell, QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton)) {
        cell->handleMouseMoveEventInsideBothButtons(mouseEvent);
    }
    else {
        cell->handleMouseMoveEventInsideLeftButton(mouseEvent);
    }
}

void CellInputHandler::cellMoveOutsideHandle(
        Cell *cell, QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton)) {
        cell->handleMouseMoveEventOutsideBothButtons(mouseEvent);
    }
    else {
        cell->handleMouseMoveEventOutsideLeftButton(mouseEvent);
    }
}
```

#### minefield.h

```
#ifndef MINEFIELD_H
#define MINEFIELD_H

#include <QVector>
#include <QWidget>

#include "cell.h"

#include <vector>

class CellInputHandler;

class Minefield : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:   
    Minefield(const QVector<Cell *> &cells, int width, int height,
              QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    [[nodiscard]] int fieldWidth() const;
    [[nodiscard]] int fieldHeight() const;
    [[nodiscard]] int countOfMines() const;
    [[nodiscard]] int minesLeft() const;

signals:
    void toggleColorInCells(int value);
    void toggleNewQuesionMarksInCells(int value);

    void uncoveredFirstCell();
    void uncoveredEmptyCell();
    void uncoveredAllSafeCells();

    void pressedCell();
    void releasedCell();

    void mineExploded();
    void minesLeftChanged(int minesLeft);  

private slots:
    void flaggedCell();
    void unflaggedCell();

    void checkIfFirstCellIsUncovered();
    void checkIfSafeCellsUncovered();    

private:   
    void connectWithCells();
    void addCellsToLayout();

    void showAllMines();
    void showWrongFlaggedCells();
    void disableInput();

    bool mFirstCellUncovered{ false };
    bool mSafeCellsUncovered{ false };
    QVector<Cell *> mCells;
    int mFieldWidth;
    int mFieldHeight;
    int mMinesLeft;
    CellInputHandler *mCellInputHandler;
};

#endif // MINEFIELD_H
```

#### minefield.cpp

```
#include "minefield.h"

#include "cell.h"
#include "cellinputhandler.h"
#include "cellutility.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QGridLayout>

Minefield::Minefield(const QVector<Cell *> &cells, int width, int height,
                     QWidget *parent)
    :QWidget{ parent },
      mCells{ cells },
      mFieldWidth{ width },
      mFieldHeight{ height },
      mMinesLeft{ countOfMines()},
      mCellInputHandler{ new CellInputHandler{ this } }
{
    Q_ASSERT(mCells.size() == (mFieldWidth * mFieldHeight));

    connectCellsWithNeighbourCells(mCells, mFieldWidth, mFieldHeight);

    for(auto &cell : mCells) {
        cell->installEventFilter(mCellInputHandler);
    }

    connectWithCells();
    addCellsToLayout();
}

int Minefield::fieldWidth() const
{
    return mFieldWidth;
}

int Minefield::fieldHeight() const
{
    return mFieldHeight;
}

int Minefield::countOfMines() const
{
    auto count = 0;
    for(const auto& cell : mCells) {
        if(cell->hasMine()) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int Minefield::minesLeft() const
{
    return mMinesLeft;
}

void Minefield::flaggedCell()
{
    --mMinesLeft;
    emit minesLeftChanged(mMinesLeft);
}

void Minefield::unflaggedCell()
{
    ++mMinesLeft;
    emit minesLeftChanged(mMinesLeft);
}


void Minefield::checkIfFirstCellIsUncovered()
{
    if(!mFirstCellUncovered) {
        mFirstCellUncovered = true;

        for(const auto &cell : mCells) {
            disconnect(cell, &Cell::uncovered,
                       this, &Minefield::checkIfFirstCellIsUncovered);
        }

        emit uncoveredFirstCell();
    }
}

void Minefield::checkIfSafeCellsUncovered()
{
    if(!mSafeCellsUncovered && allSafeCellsUncovered(mCells)) {
        mSafeCellsUncovered = true;

        for(const auto &cell : mCells) {
            disconnect(cell, &Cell::uncovered,
                       this, &Minefield::checkIfSafeCellsUncovered);
        }

        disableInput();
        emit uncoveredAllSafeCells();
    }
}

void Minefield::connectWithCells()
{
    for(const auto &cell : mCells) {
        connect(cell, &Cell::pressed,
                this, &Minefield::pressedCell);
        connect(cell, &Cell::released,
                this, &Minefield::releasedCell);

        connect(cell, &Cell::uncoveredEmptyCell,
                this, &Minefield::uncoveredEmptyCell);

        connect(cell, &Cell::flagged,
                this, &Minefield::flaggedCell);
        connect(cell, &Cell::unflagged,
                this, &Minefield::unflaggedCell);

        connect(cell, &Cell::uncovered,
                this, &Minefield::checkIfFirstCellIsUncovered);
        connect(cell, &Cell::uncovered,
                this, &Minefield::checkIfSafeCellsUncovered);

        connect(this, &Minefield::toggleNewQuesionMarksInCells,
                cell, &Cell::toggleNewQuestionMarks);
        connect(this, &Minefield::toggleColorInCells,
                cell, &Cell::toggleColor);

        if(cell->hasMine()) {
            connect(cell, &Cell::hitMine,
                    [=](){

                showWrongFlaggedCells();
                showAllMines();
                disableInput();
                emit mineExploded();
            });
        }
    }
}

void Minefield::addCellsToLayout()
{
    auto layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

    for(int i = 0; i < mCells.size(); ++i) {
        auto column = static_cast<int>(i %  mFieldWidth);
        auto row = static_cast<int>(i /  mFieldWidth);

        layout->addWidget(mCells[i], row, column);
    }
    setLayout(layout);
}

void Minefield::showAllMines()
{
    for(const auto cell : mCells) {
        if(cell->hasMine() && cell->isCovered()) {
            cell->showMine();
        }
    }
}

void Minefield::showWrongFlaggedCells()
{
    for(const auto &cell : mCells) {
        if(!cell->hasMine() && cell->isFLagged()) {
            cell->setToFlaggedWrong();
        }
    }
}

void Minefield::disableInput()
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't leak memory

I see that there are a number of places in which `new` is invoked but there is no corresponding `delete`.  For example, one leak can be addressed by adding this destructor:

```
Minefield::~Minefield() {
    delete mCellInputHandler;
}
```

### Put `friend` declarations in `public` section

It's misleading to put a `friend` declaration (as in `friend class CellInputHandler` in `cell.h`) in a `private` section.  Because access specifiers have no effect on `friend` declarations, any `friend` designation is essentially public.  For this reason, I advocate always putting `friend` declarations in `public` sections.

### Write code for human comprehension

The `Cell` constructor has this peculiar line:

```
mHasMine{ static_cast<bool>(state) },
```

I had to look up the definition of `state` and found this:

```
enum class State{
    empty,
    mine
};
```

Rather than relying on an unintuitive `static_cast`, I would suggest instead writing this:

```
  mHasMine{ state == State::mine },
```

### Put static initializers into declaration

When you have a class that has a member data items that are initialized to constants (as with `Cell`), I recommend using in-class initializers instead of explicitly listing them as part of the constructor.  See [C.48](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-in-class-initializer) for details.

### Prefer a `switch` to long `if` chain

In the `CellInputHandler::eventFilter()` we have this code:

```
if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
    handleMouseButtonPressEvents(watched, event);
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
    handleMouseButtonReleaseEvents(watched, event);
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
    handleMouseMoveEvents(event);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

I would suggest instead writing it like this:

```
bool result{true};
switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        handleMouseButtonPressEvents(watched, event);
        break;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        handleMouseButtonReleaseEvents(watched, event);
        break;
    case QEvent::MouseMove:
        handleMouseMoveEvents(event);
        break;
    default:
        result = false;
}
return result;
```

The resulting object code is likely to be very similar, but it has an advantage for human comprehension.  First, it's easy to see that only a single value is being interrogated.  Second, there is a single `return` which, to me, makes it simpler for readers of the code to understand the flow.

### Rethink your event handler

The typical approach in Qt is to have each object handle its own events.  Since `Minefield` is derived from `QWidget`, I would have expected that it would have an `event` handler.  Instead we have the separate `CellInputHandler` implemented as an `EventFilter`.  I would suggest that the events handled within `CellInputHandler` would be better expressed as part of the `event()` override function in `Minefield`.

Even better, however, would be to eliminate that completely and simply let the `Cell` objects handle their own events.  Let's consider the scenario you mentioned:

1. press left mouse button on Cell A and hold it.
2. Move out of Cell A -> Cell A gets "unpressed" on move out
3. Move into Cell B -> Cell B gets "pressed"

All that's needed is to provide handlers for `QEvent::Enter` and `QEvent::Leave`.  Pseudocode:

```
Enter: 
   if LeftMouseButtonDown, call LeftMouseButtonDown handler

Leave:
    if LeftMouseButtonDown, restore to normal state
```

**Note**: Unfortunately, as pointed out in the comment, this doesn't actually work out of the box because a `QWidget` does a `grabMouse()` on mouse button press events.  However, I suspect that one could issue an explicit `releaseMouse()` call from within the handler and still keep this approach. I may experiment with that if I get some time.

### Encapsulate more

I don't think there's much reason for any class other than `Minefield` to know about individual `Cell`s.  Therefore, I'd suggest changing the interface so that `Minefield`'s constructor is only give a width and height and all `Cell` creation and further handling would be inside the class.

Comment: my plan was to implement enter and leave in cell (it seems much cleaner) but it does not work the sliding between cells. See this discussion: https://forum.qt.io/topic/107430/detect-if-mouse-buttons-are-pressed-when-sliding-into-widget/2. The Cells are available in the constructor so I can pass not random Cells for test to the Minefield. And about the memory leak. mCellInputHandler gets the `Minefield` as its parent in the `Minefield` Constructor.so it should be deleted when `Minefield` is destroyed

Comment: I had forgotten that a widget does a MouseCapture on mouse press events, so I understand the dilemma now.  As for the memory leak, you might try running [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to check your assumption.  I did and found the application was leaking memory.

Comment: yes I will try valgrind. I think I forgot to run it. The cell think is quite a big dilemma. They way its solved now it really looks strange. I was thinking maybe the change between the cells can be implemented by using drag and drop.

Comment: I found the memory leak in the class `Game`. I make `QTime *mElapsedTime` on the heap but it never gets freed. So I freed it in the destructor. After that no more errors from valgrind

Comment: That's great!  Also, I've tried quite a few things with Qt to address the event issue and I am now persuaded that your approach with the `EventFilter` is probably the best currently available approach.  If there were an elegant way to convince Qt widgets not to `grabMouse` that would likely be better, but I haven't found a good way to do that other than the `EventFilter` approach you've already implemented.  I don't know if you've learned anything from my answer, but I have learned something from your question, so *thank you* for asking it!

Comment: dont worry i still learned some things from it. like finding the leak. theres always space to improve. getti g the game work right took me far more longer than expected especially the part with the events in zhe cells. It was a good exercise to learn more from qt

Answer (score 2):

Nice, well-presented code, apart from some spacing inconsistency following `for`, `if` etc.

---

I think the `Cell` constructor should be `explicit`.  It's odd that it's missing initializers for the timers (I use `gcc -Weffc++`, so tend to include them even for types that won't end up uninitialized).

> ```
>    constexpr auto intervall = 50;
> ```

would be better named `interval`.

---

> ```
> void Cell::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
> {
>     Q_UNUSED(event)
> ```

We could simply leave the argument unnamed instead:

```
void Cell::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
```

---

Neither `cell.cpp` nor `cellinputhandler.cpp` needs `<QDebug>`.

---

This looks suspect:

```
auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
auto widget = QApplication::widgetAt(QCursor::pos());
```

Why are we not using the event's position here, as we do in `handleMouseMoveEvents()`?  I don't think we can rely on `QCursor::pos()` being race-free relative to event delivery.

---

A bit of duplication here:

> ```
> if(!(event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton) ||
>      event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton))) {
>     return;
> }
>
> if(event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton)) {
>     mSingleMouseTimerLeft.start();
> }
> else if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton)){
>     mSingleMouseTimerRight.start();
> }
> ```

We could combine those into a single conditional:

```
if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton)) {
    mSingleMouseTimerLeft.start();
}
else if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton)) {
    mSingleMouseTimerRight.start();
}
else {
    return;
}
```

---

`minefield.h` has no need to include `<vector>` (perhaps left over from an earlier version?).

Comment: what does `-Weffc++` do? With `intervall` I guess the german in me slipped through. I thought `Q_UNUSED` is the more Qt way to hide unused parameters. Normally I tend to do `void Cell::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*event*/)` so its still possible to read the meaning.

Comment: [`-Weffc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Wno-effc_002b_002b) enables warnings about violations of several style guidelines from Scott Meyers’ _Effective C++_ series of books.

Comment: ah these books are here on my shelf. do you know how to enable this flag with qt creator?

Comment: No idea, but if it uses qmake you should be able to append to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` in the project file.  Beware that you'll want to use `-isystem` rather than `-I` for the Qt includes if you add `-Weffc++`, or you'll get a mountain of warnings from Qt's own headers!  I also found that `moc`-built sources fail my normal choice of warning flags, so had to suppress them there, too.

Comment: i added this in the pro file `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -Weffc++ -isystem` like you said i get a million warnings from qt headers. but why? i thought i enabled `isystem`

Comment: same when i write `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Weffc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem` So how to add `isystem` ?